# Integrals of odd function proof

Tags: calculus, even-and-odd-functions

I am an adult learner trying to learn calculus again. I have learnt that for an odd periodic function with period, say, T:
$$
f\left(-t\right)=-f\left(t\right)
$$
$$
\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}{f\left(t\right)dt=0}
$$
But what about if the integration interval is from 0 to T, i.e.:
$$
\int_{0}^{T}f\left(t\right)dt
$$
Will the integral still sum to 0? If yes, could anyone show me the proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Split the integral in two and use the relation between $f$ on $[-T/2,0]$ and $[T/2,T]$.

Comment: On a more general note, the integral of a $T$-periodic function on an interval of length $T$ is always the same (by using similar techniques as the one given above, one can bring any of these integral to the one over $[0,T]$).